# Why doesn't passing a lot of audits reset the review ban progression?

Tags: support, review-queues, banning

Why don't correct audits balance out failed audits in the review ban evaluation algorithm? A user can fail 3 audits, get banned for 2 days, pass 100 audits, fail 1 audit within 30 days of the last fail, and get banned again for 7 days. Doesn't a high number of passed audits indicate good review behavior and therefore should reset the ban progression to a warning or 2 days?

---

I'm currently review-banned, but this is NOT about me. I'm asking a legit question about review bans in general.

Comment: If you can't consistently pass audits that's a sign you're not paying enough attention and/or that your ability to review is not improving to the standard we need you to be at in order to do reviews. Reviewing is not a required activity, if it's not for you, stop doing it.

Comment: Why do you think anyone is interpreting this as being about you? I assume the downvotes indicate that people disagree with your idea of resetting the review ban whenever you pass an audit.

Comment: @RobertLongson Not whenever you pass AN audit. The idea is that it resets when you pass a bunch of audits, like 20 audits

Comment: This system is certainly needed. Passing more audits should weigh over failed audits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how the automatic review ban works currently.

Based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#287296) change that took place in November of 2016, automatic review bans now work as follows:

> - If the time since the last ban ended is less than or equal to 30 days, then the new ban is double the length of the last one. This is
>     not capped, meaning if the last ban was for 365 days, then the new one
>     is 730.
> - If the time since the last ban ended is greater than 30 days, then the new ban is half the length of the last ban or 2 days - whichever
>     is greater.

So there's actually a way to regress the amount of time you'll be banned for - don't get banned again within 30 days.

Further, failing a single audit usually won't result in an automatic ban, you have to fail more than one.

In general, the amount of succeeded audits is taken into consideration for when the review ban is triggered - for instance, if you fail 3 audits back to back, you can almost be certain to get one. But if you fail one, succeed 10, fail one, suceed 10 etc you have a higher chance of not being banned. The exact details of how the ban works are secret to prevent gaming it, but that's the gist.

Comment: This answer presents the current behaviour, but it doesn't answer the *why* part.

Answer (score 3):

Magisch explains the how, as to the why: even people who blindly click buttons in review get review audits correct at a certain rate. Unless you're reviewing in the suggested edit queue (where all audits should be rejected), you have a certain percentage chance that clicking the same action over and over will pass an individual audit. If you're lucky, this can pass a string of audits. Moderators can look for patterns of bad reviews that slip through audits, but we don't have a lot of time to find these.

We also don't want to encourage people to review sloppily in large volumes, getting things mostly right but making many mistakes along the way.

Anecdotally, I've seen many cases of bad or completely inattentive reviewers who would have had legitimate review bans nullified by your proposal. They would have continued to do damage to the site by letting bad content in, instead of being stopped.

If someone approves spam or vandalism, it doesn't matter how many audit passes they had before that. I'm not saying that every audit is as obvious as that, and we certainly have problems with bad audits from time to time, but audits do tend to work well to catch problematic reviews.