# What is the reason for a reviewer make a review?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I think most of the users are trying to review only because of some pixels, which are named badge. And since this is only one thing user gets for spending his own time, I don't see any reason to do this.

For one mistake user gets punished with a ban and there is no possibility to avoid this mistakes, because of sometimes just bad audits. There are many posts created already, where users are complaining about bad audits and got banned just for one mistake. And it absolutelly doesn't matter how many good reviews user had before.

It seems to me like moderators cannot or don't want to deal with this situation. People, who are trying to make this site better, just getting punnished for one silly mistake or even bad audit.

I just don't get the point of being punished for free. Am I missing something?

From my perspective there should be the completely new review system, where user's good reviews could be also counted. For example for 100 reviews you may make 1 mistake. This system exists already with flags. If your flags are helpful, you can raise more flags. This makes sence. But now for reviews doesn't matter the quality, you have just to pass the audit. I think that's why there are so many discussions about hordes of robo-reviewers.

EDIT:

SO gives you 3 attempts to fail an audit for the whole time. Once you have failed 3 times, you will get banned. And then every fail will cause a ban. For 100 reviews it is more than enough, for 1000 probably not anymore. For 10 000? So, there should be a ratio for this system. For example I have passed 10 audits and got 1 time to fail the audit in the future. Something like this.

Comment: Your first sentence answers your question title. Anyway, I'm not sure what you're proposing here. Flat out removing review audits?

Comment: No, I don't do reviews because of the badge.

Comment: *users [...] got banned just for one mistake.* citation needed.

Comment: It's never been 'just one mistake'. You have to have a certain number of bad reviews to be banned. To be banned for one review, a moderator had to manually dish out the ban, which I've only seen happen on egregiously bad reviews.

Comment: @Patrice once you didn't pass the audit, you will get banned.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov: No, this is not true. A single failed audit will not get you banned.

Comment: @BDL Really? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov: Where in this answer do you read that a single failed audit will get you banned?

Comment: @Rob I am proposing a system, where good reviews can "save" you from getting banned

Comment: @BDL "failed only one, it's important" it is in the question

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov failed only one after being banned previously; which means more failed audits.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov: Op failed on review audit **after being banned**. This means they failed multiple, got banned, then failed again. So if you fail an audit in the 30 days after being banned: Yes, that will get you banned again. But just failing one single audit on it's own won't get you banned.

Comment: @BDL from the scratch you have I think 3 times to fail the review, what is ok. But once you get banned this counter is not set to 3 again. It will remain at 1, why? What If I doing 100 reviews, or 1000. It is a big number. And SO is expecting only 3 times me to fail?

Comment: Basically; there is no way to detect “good” reviews. We can only try to detect “bad” reviewers with audits.

Comment: @yivi that's the point of my post. There should be a way to have some more attemts.

Comment: @Andrei but it does reset. After long enough. If you didn't learn from the ban and *immediately* continue doing dubious reviews, it shouldn't give you another 3 chances.... You need to prove to the system you know what you are doing. It... Makes sense

Comment: @Patrice how long does it takes until reset? Any link to this information?

Comment: @Andrei not sure. If memory serves, 30 days (although I am exhausted today and wouldn't trust my memory... Could be a # of audits too, really not sure). There are meta discussions about this somewhere. I don't see myself finding them on my phone though.

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370758/why-doesnt-passing-a-lot-of-audits-reset-the-review-ban-progression) are some more details on how the ban works. I guess the details are kept secret in order to prevent gaming the system.

Comment: "It seems to me like moderators cannot or don't want to deal with this situation." - On the contrary, I keep bringing up [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/135615) as a way to work against bad audits every time I can. I'll also point out that your latest review ban was manually applied by a moderator when community members pointed out reviews like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21592686), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21592921), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21592811). We actively monitor review.

Comment: @Patrice I have access to 8 queues. The CV queue typically lets you go to 40. Simple math tells you that's a max of 180 reviews/day (assuming no other queues overflow), or 5400 in a 30 day period. Having served review bans before, not being able to make a single mistake in over 5000 reviews is absurd. I'm not saying that most people do that many, but I could certainly see myself doing 2000 per month if I weren't limiting myself to the queues I know I will never fail an audit in. Actions like that should not be necessary.

Comment: @jhpratt but it's only '1 mistake in 5000' after you've done enough to get banned in the first place. I have served bans as well. I can't say I am currently active in review queues (as the kid grows I don't have that much idle time for Stack), but I believe if you do reviews slowly, considering everything, and skipping when you ain't sure, it's very feasibly to get to that. Or to close enough that you won't ever get banned in the first place, which then makes it so you never have to get to that 1 in 5000

Comment: Oh and btw, if the problem only arises when you're going 'quite fast through queues' (as you posted on yivi's answer)... Isn't the intent of audits (to make sure you *slow down* and pay more attention) achieved? If you get caught by audits when you're rushing, it's a good sign you should slow down a bit. If you took an extra 5 minutes per review, would you still fail when you rush? In all likelihood, you wouldn't...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the reason for reviewer make an review? [sic]

It depends on the reviewer. Badges and gamification can be a factor. But it hass been proved many times over that there are users that earn all possible badges that is possible to earn from review... *and they keep on reviewing*.

For some it will be simply because they want to make the site better for everybody. Or because they want to help taking out the trash so the site remains useful *for them*. Or because they are still engaged in seeing their counter go up. Or simply because they find it alluring in its own way, as popping bubble wrap.

In the end it is a personal reason. But no matter the reason a reviewer has, the system wants reviewers to perform a specific function by participating in the review queues.

> For one mistake user gets punished with a ban

This is simply false. It takes more than one failed audit to be automatically banned.

> and there is no possibility to avoid this mistakes, because of sometimes just bad audits.

While I can't flat out say that it's *impossible* to avoid falling into audit traps, I can say, categorically, that failing many audits is *hard*. It's been pointed again and again that most audits are too easy and obvious to spot.

If you fail many audits too often, maybe you need to choose your review tasks more carefully. Filtering posts, for example. Using *skip* more often. Pickig the right review queue for you.

> I just don't get the point of being punished for free.

You are not *really* being punished. The only "punishment" is that someone is taking away the bubble wrap you were currently popping. Instead of thinking of this as punishment, think of it as a time-out to regroup because your current approach may not to be aligned with the purpose of the review queues.

You can use the warning to read on review guidance, to bring the issue to meta to see if it really was a case of a bad audit, or to pursue other targets (e.g. you can answer questions, use your full-edit privilege to fix other posts, etc).

> From my perspective there should be the completely new review system, where user's good reviews could be also counted. For example for 100 reviews you may make 1 mistake.

Detecting *good* reviews is simply not possible. At most we can detect passed audits, but that doesn't take much in the vast majority of cases. It doesn't seem very  useful to give anyone a lot of credence because they "passed audits".

Passing audits is expected. And doesn't prove that the rest of your reviews were any good. Audits are there not to punish/reward reviewers, but they intend to catch patterns in the actions of a reviewer. **Passing an audit is absence of evidence, not evidence of absence.**

We can all fail occasionally  (I have no idea how many audits I have personally failed, I imagine is more than one), but the expectation is that if you are going to participate in review (which is something completely optional, that doesn't give you any other privileges in the site) failing any number should be a clear warning sign that either something is wrong with how you are reviewing, or with the audits you got.

(The latter does happen: if you report these cases of "bad" audits moderators can take action so it doesn't count against your record; and most of the time the community can take action so they are no longer part of the audit pool).

Comment: Ok, I got your point and won't do reviews with the system currently exists. You have 3 times to fail before your first ban and then every fail will cause next ban. And it doesn't matter how many reviews you did already. Even if it is hard to fail audits(I agree), anyway you will fail some of them just because we are humans and fail sometimes. I don't aggree with a ban every time I fail

Comment: @yivi: You forgot about procrastination.

Comment: @BDL In what sense? I'm sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: @yivi: Sorry. Was a bad joke. I meant procrastination is usually my main motivation to do reviews.

Comment: @BDL Wasn't that bad. Sorry we had to kill it by explaining it.

Comment: 3 'sorry' in 3 comments? And I though I was the Canadian....

Comment: @Patrice I regret I apologized too much and too often. Hopefully I won't get sorry-banned. :P

Comment: "I can say, categorically, that failing many audits is hard. It's been pointed again and again that most audits are too easy and obvious to spot." → I can work my way through some queues quite quickly, which is enough to trigger an audit. I almost always recognize it as an audit, but the _increased rate_ causes me to fail on occasion (as anyone would do). The system doesn't take into account _passed audits_, which is the problem IMO.

Answer (score 12):

The reason is to make a *difference*. Review is set up to help ensure that Stack Overflow's content remains relevant, curated and helpful. Audits were introduced because some people needed more than the intrinsic motivation that comes from knowing you did something worthwhile, some folks just wanted to collect the badges, as you noted.

Continually getting ensnared by audits doesn't necessarily mean that you are "robot reviewing", it just means that your opinion of what action should have been taken often differs from what a bunch of other people agreed should happen. This means that you just often find yourself disagreeing with how certain types of posts are handled.

If that's the case, the thing to do is bring some of these up not in the context of "here's a bad audit" but "I don't think we're handling this kind of post as well as we could be". Because, essentially, that's the root of it.

Take a second and think of building blocks, like, say, LEGO bricks. You get a set and you can build a house, or a spaceship, or something. The final thing you build means more to you than the sum of all of the blocks, because you built it, *that's* the reward for reviewing, the badge is commemorative so you can look back on it.

I understand what you're trying to say, but I think you're looking at the problem from the wrong angle. Most likely, the best idea is to pick several of these audits and:

- Come here to ask questions about them. Look for the *why*, as in "Why (this action) instead of this one?"
- Use some of them as an example of saying "I don't think it's possible for people to anticipate the kinds of actions we take" - that might not mean people will / should stop, but it points out holes where we don't set expectations well

Just always be humble and make it clear you're here in an honest attempt to figure things out, and you'll probably do well.

But this post? It was really hard for me to figure out what points you wanted to make, and I'm not 100% certain I got it right, so feel free to correct me :) I think you have a lot of energy you want to give, there are just obstacles, and maybe you need help identifying them, and in that process, maybe you've got some perspective to give back too.

But it's hard to tell from what you wrote here, as helpful feedback.

Comment: I understand the point of punishing system, also why it was introduced. But do you think, that 3 mistakes for the whole time are enough? I mean after 3 times, you will get banned, what is ok. But after that, every mistake will cause a ban, what from my perspective is not ok. What if I am making many reviews? For every mistake ban?

Comment: No, @Andrei. Many “mistakes” won’t result in bans. Only the ones that happen to be audits. That’s the problem.